# How to define a subset that is equal to the parent set after deduplication

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For example, I have a set $A=\{1,1,2,3,3,3\}$, and after removing duplicate items, I get $B=\{1,2,3\}$.
I would like to know how to define such a set $B$.

Comment: You seem to want $A$ to be a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) not a set (if it were a set then $B=A$).  I would have thought if you say $B$ is a set then  $B=\{x:x \in A\}$

Comment: If $A$ is a set then $A$ is already $\{1,2,3\}$ i.e. $B=A$.

Comment: A is a list, B is a set

Comment: I don't think there is a universally accepted word for that, people just say something like "the set of distinct elements in the multiset $A$".

Comment: I see. It looks like I got confused about the concepts of multiset and set.